# Does java have a keyword "that"

Tags: java

I recently came across the following article which talks about `that` keyword in java. http://rebelutionary.blogs.atlassian.com/2003/08/jsr666_the_that.html

Please explain the usage with code examples.

Comment: Look at what it does. Obviously impossible, so a joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an April Fool's prank to me. Note the number '666'. Also see [an explanation](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2003/02/03/jsr666/).